# No path error for class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This should work fine:

```
#comment.rb
def next
    self.class.where("id > ?", id).first
end

#comments_controller.rb
def show
    find_comment
    @next_comment = @comment.next
end

#show.html.haml
= link_to "next", @next_comment

#routes.rb
resources :articles do
  resources :comments
end
```

I am getting an `undefined method comment_path` error.

What am I missing? Please let me know if there are any files I have not included.

UPDATE:

Okay, thanks to @pascal betz it goes to the correct URL. The error I get now is `undefined method article for nil:NilClass`, pointing to the button line in the show page:

`= link_to 'Next', article_comment_path(@next_comment.article, @next_comment)`

Comment: What does rake routes produce?

Comment: Your update: it means that @next_comment is nil. Have you inspected that? There will not always be a next comment. So you need to make this link conditional (only if next_comment is present). Does that help?

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `comments` are nested under `articles`.

You can create the link like so:

```
link_to 'next', [@next_comment.article, @next_comment]
```

or

```
link_to 'next', article_comment_path(@next_comment.article, @next_comment)
```

This will create an URL like

`articles/123/comments/456`

Where 123 is the article id and 456 is the comment id.

About finding the next comment: i'd probably go for a DateTime such as `created_at` or `posted_at` (whatever you have in your model) instead of the primary key.

Comment: Where do you get this error?
On the "next comment" page?
Probably there is no next comment. You need to render this link conditionally.

Comment: Well, there is not enough information to help you. What is the template looking like, what is the error message.

Comment: Update your question with the relevant information. What line does the error appear. Show the source code.

I assume it is in @next_comment.article. Which would indicate that the it is not initialised